# Not defining function directly in Event listener

Tags: jquery

This is a simple listener:

```
$("#target").keypress(function(event) {
  alert("test");
});
```

I want to take separate function out but it won't work:

```
$("#target").keypress(doAlert(event));

function doAlert(event)
{
  alert("test");
}
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want:

```
$("#target").keypress(doAlert);
```

Your original:

```
$("#target").keypress(doAlert(event));
```

...***calls*** the `doAlert` function and passes its return value into `keypress`, just like any other function call. You want to give `keypress` a *reference* to the `doAlert` function, you don't want to give it `doAlert`'s return value. (If `doAlert` created and returned an event handler function you might do that, but that's not what you've written.)

Answer (score 0):

It won't work because with `doAlert(event)` you are **calling** *the function right away*. Remember in JS, you *call* functions by putting `()` after there names, that's what you are doing there which won't work because `keypress` needs **callback**, which runs after `keypress` handler is finished.

So, you should have:

```
$("#target").keypress(doAlert);
```